# how do i make partitions in ubuntu for data storing?

Tags: 17.04

I am a beginner and I want to install only Ubuntu 17.04 on my Laptop and I want to partition my 1 TB hard drive for different data storage.

Answer (score 0):

For me the best way is to partition the drive before the actual installation. For this I start the installation DVD into the Ubuntu Live system. This has the graphical partition tool gparted on the program menu.

I use that to create all partitions I need, including a small swap partition for linux. When I want to access a data partition from other computers I usually use NTFS.

Then I start the installation by clicking the installation icon on the live desktop and select the intended partition for the system.

Comment: Normaly there are no needs to partition before installing, especially  not if you want to install Ubuntu as only system. Just chose to use all disk, or 'something else' if you want a special partition layout.

Comment: I am sorry to disagree. As the OP references data storage explicitly it is imho always a good idea to keep that separated from the OS. Typically on a net share, but also on a data partition. This is especially useful if you use clonzilla and the like for backup. You can always restore an old backup without erasing your data. You can add additional linux partitions any time later and many more advantages. In case it was your down vote for that reason I think it was unfair.

Comment: That's what `Something else` is for; Making separate /home, /var or something else ...

Comment: Surely a possibility. Still you would best put those onto a separate partition. Whether or not a beginner benefits from facing a distributed system folder setup is a different question.

Comment: I also like to use a separate **data** partition, and I can recommend it. If only linux in the computer, I use the `ext4` file system and if dual booting with Windows, or in a USB pendrive, I use the `NTFS` file system to make it available also by Windows. Things are more convenient after creating a line in `/etc/fstab` to mount this data partition in a reliable way. I also add a label, for example 'data', to make it easier to recognize the partition. -- With a data partition you can separate the backup of data from the backup of the operating system.